# Selecting all the descendants of a tree node

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, adjacency-list

I'm using the adjacency list model to store a (very dynamic) tree structure in a MySQL database. I need a way to select all of the descendants of a given node, preferably via a single call to a stored routine. I know that the nested sets model would make this easy, but it would make other things very difficult, so unfortunately it's not an option for me. Here's what I've got so far:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE get_descendants(node_id INT)
    BEGIN

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS descendants;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE descendants (id INT, name VARCHAR(100), parent_id INT);

    INSERT INTO descendants
        SELECT *
        FROM nodes
        WHERE parent_id <=> node_id;

    -- ...?

    END//

DELIMITER ;
```

The idea is to keep drilling down and appending children to the descendants table until I reach the leaves. I can then access the temporary table from outside the procedure...I hope. (It really sucks that I can't return a result set from a stored function.)

I need to somehow loop over the results and issue a new SELECT statement for each row. I've read that cursors might help here, but I don't see how. It seems like with cursors you have to select everything up front, then iterate.

Comment: Nested sets is not your only option.  Closure tables are worth looking into too.

Comment: Actually, I just discovered closure tables this afternoon! They seem promising, but they don't handle move operations very well. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/02/14/moving-subtrees-in-closure-table/ In that sense, they're kind of like nested sets. I'll keep studying.

Comment: choosing the appropriate data structure for your needs is all about understanding how often you'll need to do different types of operations - as every solution trades off time against space in different ways.  If your graph is fairly static and you often need to inspect paths through it, then an adjacency list is probably not the best choice; however, it might be the ideal solution if the graph's very dynamic and you rarely need to inspect more than the immediately adjacent neighbours of any given node.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to `read : write` ratio. If you have very high rate of reading, it will be very helpful to make a full-relationship table, not a temporary one.

A pseudo approach (Not a real code!) :

```
1. node(1) has child node(2)
     -> Insert a row with (parent_id = 1, child_id = 2, direct = True)

2. node(2) has child node(3)
     -> Insert a row with (parent_id = 2, child_id = 3, direct = True)
     -> Choose all ascendants of node(2)
     -> Ascendants of node(2) : [node(1)]
     -> Insert a row with (parent_id = 1, child_id = 3, direct = False)

3. To retrieve all descendants of node(1)
     -> SELECT child_id FROM [table] WHERE parent_id = 1;

4. To retrieve children of node(1)
     -> SELECT child_id FROM [table] WHERE parent_id = 1 AND direct = True;

5. To retrieve all ascendants of node(3)
     -> SELECT parent_id FROM [table] WHERE child_id = 3;

6. To retrieve parent of node(3)
     -> SELECT parent_id FROM [table] WHERE child_id = 3 AND direct = True;

+-----------+----------+--------+
| parent_id | child_id | direct |
+-----------+----------+--------|
|         1 |        2 | True   |
|         1 |        3 | False  |
|         2 |        3 | True   |
....
+-----------+----------+--------+
Index 1 on ( parent_id, direct )
Index 2 on ( child_id, direct )
```

This approche has a bad performance while updating relationships. Use at your own risk.